# How is Rayman Legends different on different consoles?

Tags: rayman-legends

I just picked up Rayman Legends on my WiiU. It's clear from the start that this game has some heavy GamePad integration - half the first level involves poking, swiping, and rotating to victory.

This led me to wonder: what does the game do for the PS3 & 360 versions, which don't have a GamePad built in? Is the game significantly different?  Would it make sense to have multiple copies on multiple consoles for maximum platformy goodness?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rayman Legends on other systems is much different than the WiiU version. One of the main differences is that you don't control Murphy, the flying character who helps clear your paths.

For more information on the differences, watch the this video to see side-by-side gameplay of levels: [Click for video](http://www.gametrailers.com/videos/e1ei5m/rayman-legends-wii-u---xbox-360-level-comparison)

Comment: Wow that's a real shame -- playing as Murphy is one of the most fun parts of this game IMHO!